# Como selecionar linhas que coincidem uma das colunas em tabelas diferentes?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho duas tabelas: uma em que cadastro os jogos da rodada e a outra que cadastra os palpites para esses jogos. Eu quero mostrar uma tabela onde apareça o Jogo, o palpite do usuário X e caso ele já tenha sido jogado, seu resultado também. No momento, a solução que encontrei é a seguinte:

Eu seleciono todos os jogos da rodada X. Aí eu faço um while e dentro dele faço uma nova seleção para encontrar o palpite daquele usuário. Ele está funcionando normalmente, mas temo que seja algo errado pela quantidade grande de queries sendo feitas. Se uma rodada tem 16 jogos, eu seleciono uma vez todos os jogos dela + 16 seleções de cada palpite. Isso fora as outras queries da página. Há alguma solução mais enxuta? É possível com dois selects apenas pegar todas informações necessárias?

Edit:

São 2 tabelas relevantes a essa pergunta:

Tabela Jogos:
id - timecasa - timefora - resultado

Tabela Palpites:

id - idjogo (mesmo do id da tabela jogos) - idusuario (de quem fez o palpite) - escolha (se ele escolheu o time de casa ou fora) - resultado

Comment: O que você quer é um JOIN, os palpites é de todos usuários ou apenas de um? Coloque a sua estrutura do banco, onde está os resultados?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, você deveria ter nos dado a estrutura das tabelas, pelo que me parece você deverá buscar algo que está em mais de duas tabelas, veja:

1. Uma Tabela com os jogos
2. Uma tabela com os dados da aposta
3. Uma tabela com os dados do apostador(Essa tabela geralmente é a tabela onde os usuários são cadastrados)

Esquema(Tabela 'jogos')

```
+----------------------
|       jogos         |
+---------------------+
| id | desc_jogo      |
+---------------------+
| 1  | Jogo de Futebol|
+---------------------+
| 2  | Jogo de Peteca |
+---------------------+
```

Esquema(Tabela 'apostadores')

```
+----------------------
|    apostadores      |
+---------------------+
| id | nome           |
+---------------------+
| 1  | João Pedro     |
+---------------------+
| 2  | José           |
+---------------------+
```

Esquema(Tabela 'apostas')

```
+--------------------------------+
|            apostas             |
+--------------------------------+
| id | jogos_id | apostadores_id |
+--------------------------------+
| 1  |    1     |       1        |
+--------------------------------+
| 2  |    1     |       2        |
+--------------------------------+
```

Imagine esse cenário e aplique no seu sistema, o modo que você está fazendo utilizando while é o pior que se pode imaginar, imagine se seu banco de dados tivesse milhões de apostadores... Pense sempre em casos extremos, espere o pior caso e planeje sua aplicação para lidar com eles.Vamos deixar tudo para o MySQL, ele é bom nisso. Veja o comando que você utilizará:

```
SELECT apostas.id AS id, jogos.desc_jogo AS jogo, apostadores.nome AS apostador FROM apostas INNER JOIN jogos_id ON jogos_id = jogos.id INNER JOIN apostadores ON apostadores_id = apostadores.id WHERE jogos_id = 1
```

Isso nos retornaria algo assim:

```
+----------------------------------+
| id |      jogo      |  apostador |
+----------------------------------+
| 1  |Jogo de Futebol | João Pedro |
+----------------------------------+
| 2  |Jogo de Futebol | José       |
+----------------------------------+
```